# Connecting to Remote PHP interpreter from bash

Tags: php, docker, unix-socket

I am not sure if this possible to do.

My scenario is:

I have a docker setup with 4 containers:

1. PHP-FPM
2. DB
3. Nginx
4. some batch processor

I understand that NGINX uses the unix socket to integrate with the PHP container. Without (4) in the picture, the setup is just as perfect.

What I am trying to accomplish is, from (4) I want to execute some php script on PHP-FPM(1) container. Before coming to a point to post this question here, I searched whether it was possible to use remote PHP interpreter from bash for this purpose. But a majority of the articles were about PHPStorm. As an example, a basic example to run a simple php script using the remote interpreter would be fine.

Can I accomplish this particular feature of PHPStorm using bash or some other scripts? But this has to be from the command line.

Any inputs or feedback on this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, usually `ssh` is the tool of choice to connect to a remote system and execute some command. Certainly it is possible to execute some php command that way.

Comment: @arkascha yes you are right. that would have been a simpler task. But if you take a look at the steps to connect to a remote php interpreter via PHP Storm, they rely on "docker.sock". My curiosity was whether I could achieve that from a custom script or not. I can mount the docker.sock from host to the guest container(4). But I am not sure if that will help me out.

Comment: What _might_ be what you are looking for is that instead of operating the php engine in a local fcgi environment inside the containers http server you can also directly connect to it from the outside _if_ you setup the fcgi environment in such manner. So that you expose the socket it listens to to the outside (of the container) and connect to that port from your IDE or cli utility. Possible, but kind of _exotic_.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you are trying to achieve here.

You already have a way of executing PHP remotely via the webserver.

It would be very unusual to implement a Unix server (probably Linux since we're talking about Docker - you should have mentioned) without ssh access - in which case, it's trivial to...

```
 ssh remoteuser@yourserver "/usr/bin/php /path/to/yourscript.php"
```

But assuming for some reason you don't have ssh access....

I can only guess that you want to execute the script from the command line to dissociate it from the webserver process as a [long running script](https://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html) (although that shouldn't be an issue for nginx) or to run it with different privileges - [sudo does that](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo). Sudo can also run as a [different SELinux user](https://serverfault.com/questions/537912/granting-sudo-access-to-a-selinux-confined-user-in-freeipa).

Comment: sorry for the unclear or confusing text in the question. Let's say container(4) is a job-processor or cron jobs processor. I was trying to decouple this from php container. there could be PHP jobs as well as some db jobs or some code-backup jobs, etc.
What I was trying to do is periodically execute some code using the PHP interpreter in the container (1). That's what PHP Storm also does, right ? But, I guess they are relying on docker.sock there. I am not sure if it is clear yet.